# Meteor & Cloud 9 IDE: Enable CORS

Tags: rest, http, meteor, iron-router, cloud9-ide

I am developing a REST API in Meteor and have successfully set up my project in Cloud 9 IDE after local development in order to test successfull calls to my HTTP methods. If I enter path URIs in my browser, I get the data that I want. However, calling the methods from within Fiddler or Client side test clients results in 302 (Temporarily moved) HTTP response and what appears to be a redirect page, provided by the C9 IDE platform.

Is there any way to surpass this? I believe I have handled CORS well, so this should not give problems. See the following (simplified) Meteor example of how my routes and CORS handling in my app look like.

```
var handleRequest = function(context, funcToExec) {
    context.response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    var requestMethod = context.request.method.toUpperCase();

    if (requestMethod === "OPTIONS" ) {
        //TODO: Uncomment this!
        context.response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' );
        context.response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        context.response.end('Set OPTIONS.');

        return true;
    } else {
        //Get the data from the function
        var data = funcToExec(context);

        //Send it back to the client
        context.response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        context.response.statusCode = 200;
        context.response.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
};

Router.route(/* route here */, function() {
    handleRequest(this, function(c) {
        //Extract context query parameters, do some work and return the data
        //...

        var data = {key: 'key', value: 'data'};

        return data;
    });
}, {where: server});
```

The project runner setup was done via the IDE (by setting the CWD and choosing the Meteor runner). I've included the default (and current) run script below. Maybe there's options available to make the service respond properly to HTTP calls from outside?

```
{
  "cmd": [
    "meteor",
    "--port",
    "$PORT"
  ],
  "info": "Meteor",
  "working_dir": "$project_path",
  "env": {
    "NODE_OPTIONS": "${debug?--debug-brk=<PORT>}",
    "ROOT_URL": "https://$C9_HOSTNAME",
    "BIND_IP": "$IP"
  },
  "debugger": "v8",
  "debugport": <PORT>
}
```

**EDIT - PROBLEM SOLVED:** As Mutahhir pointed out, your Application URL must be set to public in order to call the application from outside.

Comment: Is your application url public? This seems like its hitting Cloud9 authentication. Try accessing your application from an incognito window to check.

Comment: @Mutahhir: Just checked and you're right: I'm hitting Cloud9 authentication window. I just checked and it seems I've forgot to make my application URL public... Thanks for pointing this out!